# Conversion of float numbers to a formatted string

Tags: c++, boost, formatting, printf

I'm trying to convert a `double` number to a `std::string`, the conversion should print either in the decimal format with 2 decimal digits or in the exponential form:

1. 1 -> 1.00
2. 0.1 -> 0.10
3. 0.01 -> 0.01
4. 0.015 -> 1.5e-2
5. 10 -> 10.00
6. 100 -> 100.00
7. 15000 -> 1.5e4

I tried to use the `boost::format` function with the `%g` type, but while it is possible to set the number of significant digits, it's not possible to set the number of printed digits after the decimal point:

1. 1 -> 1
2. 0.1 -> 0.1
3. 0.01 -> 0.01
4. 10 -> 10
5. 100 -> 100

Is there a better way of doing this kind of conversion/formatting? I would preferably use the Standard Library or Boost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose `scientific` or `fixed` depending on the size of the number.

It's that easy.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: This is correct for iostream output. Combine with `setprecision` to limit printed digits.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to check the size of numbers and still have a pretty output. I'll just keep using boost::format (it outputs nice i18n formatted numbers) and check the size of the numbers before setting the formatting mask.

Answer (score 3):

No boost needed although there should be a way to do this with `boost::format` or `sprintf` if you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string numStr("3.14159265");
    double num(atof(numStr.c_str()));
    std::cout
        << std::setprecision(2) 
        << std::scientific << num
        << std::fixed << num;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Misread the question if you want to go from `double` to `std::string` I'd use a `std::ostringstream` which supports the same iostream manipulators and insertion operator. Then you can call `str()` to get a string out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ostringstream, like so

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string FloatToString(float fNumber)
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    os << fNumber;

    return os.str();
}
```

Comment: Just exchange float for double

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but...
You can control the number of printed digits using cout with  using the setprecision function.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double d = 123123.23234234;
  cout << setprecision(15) << d;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't address very large or very little numbers, which should be formatted using exponential notation.

Answer (score 0):

sprintf() ; should be easy to help you print double into a string/char array .

Comment: Isn't this just the same as ZeroDiv's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729162/conversion-of-float-numbers-to-a-formatted-string/7729285#7729285?

Comment: sorry didn't see that. I can delete my answer if you suggest. !!

Answer (score -1):

Plain old C sprintf supports # of decimals like so: "%.3g"

You can turn the char* output into a std::string easily enough.

Comment: -1:  True, but sprintf is type unsafe and unadvised in C++.  Plus you'd have to allocate some crappy char buffer first.  Yuck.

Comment: boost::format has the same features as sprintf. The "%.3g" flag will allow me to set the significant digits for exponential numbers but not the decimal digits for decimal float point numbers.

Comment: Huh ... then boost::format doesn't have *exactly* the same features as sprintf, because %.3g with sprintf will always produce exactly three digits to the right of the decimal point. (Admission: I've barely used boost.)

Comment: `boost::format` is similar but not the same as `sprintf` ... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_differences